# Using Array.reduce function with objects in a NgRx application

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, reducers, ngrx-entity

In a NgRx Angular 5 project, there is a use of the reduce function i don't really understand. I would appreciate some help

Basically the code iterates an array of object and the array looks like this:

```
[{
   id: '0',
   message: 'work',
   done: false
 },
 {
   id: '1',
   message: 'movie',
   done: false
 },
 {
   id: '2',
   message: 'Play',
   done: false
 }]
```

In my NgRx reducer, there is the following block of code :

```
case todosAction.FETCH_TODO_SUCCESS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    //action.payload contains above array of objects
    datas: action.payload.reduce((accumulateur, iteration) => {
      accumulateur[iteration.id] = iteration;
      return accumulateur;
    }, { ...state.datas }),
    loading: false,
    loaded: true,
    error: null 
  };
}
```

The state i'm using looks like this:

```
export interface TodoState {
  datas: {
    [todoId: string]: Todo
  }
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
  error: any;
}
```

We use the reduce function here to transform the original source which is an array of object to entities ( a key which is an id associated to a `todo` object).
I understand the reason why we use this function but i don't understand its inner code:

```
action.payload.reduce((accumulateur, iteration) => {
          accumulateur[iteration.id] = iteration; // <-- AS FAR AS I UNDERSTAND, ACCUMULATOR IS NOT AN ARRAY, HOW CAN WE ACHIEVE SUCH A THING
          return accumulateur;
        }, { ...state.datas })
```

Thank you in advance for helping me to put some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that

`state.datas` equals to:

```
{
  '0': {
    id: '0',
    message: 'Hello',
    done: false
  }
}
```

`action.payload` equals

```
[{
  id: '1',
  message: 'World',
  done: false
}]
```

After the reducer returns you will end up with

```
{
  '0': {
    id: '0',
    message: 'Hello',
    done: false
  },
  '1': {
    id: '1',
    message: 'World',
    done: false
  }
}
```

The important thing to note is that the id is a string. You can have an object with a key of `'0'`. It's no different than using any other string.

Comment: Thank you for helping,

In the reducer, do we agree that the initial accumulateur value is {
   id: '0',
   message: 'work',
   done: false
 } 
?

This is not an array,  why can we use this : 
accumulateur[iteration.id] = iteration;

Comment: The initial value is `{
  '0': {
    id: '0',
    message: 'Hello',
    done: false
  }
}` . You can set properties values on objects like this: `const x = {}` `x['0'] = 'hello`'.

Comment: It helped me. Thank you !